# How to echo a string in liunx with nested quotes

Tags: node.js, linux

I am really tired trying to find a solution, hope someone can help
I am trying to run a single line command using node exec function after making a ssh connection

the command is something like:

```
ssh user@1.1.1.1 'echo "echo \"{\"a\":\"A\"}\""'\
```

but this is giving

```
echo "{"active":"os1","os1":"3.1.0-r5"}"
```

what I want is

```
echo '{"active":"os1","os1":"3.1.0-r5"}'
```

what can I do here ?

Comment: What does this have to do with node.js?

Comment: I'm trying to run the whole command in an exec function

Comment: Then show that JavaScript code. Things get more complicated when you're embedding shell commands inside JavaScript strings, since you have to escape the backslashes.